# Powerful NVIDIA is slower than old AMD CPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I trained with Keras/TensorFlow the following NN with the layers: 6 LSTM + 42 LSTM + 42 LSTM + 2 Dense.
The input tensor has the shape (653015, 240, 6), so it's quite big (~3.5 GB).

I tried it on paperspace.com Cloud GPU instance with dedicated NVIDIA Quadro P4000. One epoch took ~ 9000 sec. When I tried raining on my home old AMD Athlon X4 760K, an epoch took ~ 7000 seconds.

When the trainig started it showed:

```python
2018-04-05 10:08:22.845846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro P4000
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.48
pciBusID 0000:00:05.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.59GiB
2018-04-05 10:08:22.845885: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0
2018-04-05 10:08:22.845892: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y
2018-04-05 10:08:22.845900: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro P4000, pci bus id: 0000:00:05.0)
```

So, it definitely used GPU but not CPU.

nvidia-smi showed:

```python
Thu Apr  5 11:46:38 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 00000000:00:05.0  On |                  N/A |
| 46%   41C    P0    29W / 105W |   7799MiB /  8114MiB |     21%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2593      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           169MiB |
|    0      2913      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         106MiB |
|    0      3360      C   python3                                     7511MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvidia-smi dmon:

```python
# gpu   pwr  temp    sm   mem   enc   dec  mclk  pclk
# Idx     W     C     %     %     %     %   MHz   MHz
    0    32    43    21     1     0     0  3802  1202
    0    29    43    19     2     0     0  3802  1202
    0    31    43    15     1     0     0  3802  1202
    0    32    43    18     1     0     0  3802  1202
    0    29    43    20     1     0     0  3802  1202
    0    29    43    20     2     0     0  3802  1202
    0    29    43    19     1     0     0  3802  1202
```

When I replaced LSTM layer in my NN with CuDNNLSTM, NVIDIA training took about 3800 seconds. But it's only 2 times faster then on old CPU.

Could anyone explain how to troubleshoot why NVIDIA is so slow in this training?
I have no idea what to do.

The author of this article https://medium.com/initialized-capital/benchmarking-tensorflow-performance-and-cost-across-different-gpu-options-69bd85fe5d58 demonstrated that paperspace instances much faster then Core i7.

Comment: You don't show your code so it is very hard to tell. But GPU usage is very low, usually an indication of a bottleneck in feeding input data to the model. All the computation power in the world will not help if the GPU is spending most of the time waiting for data.

Comment: Yes, the input is so big that moving it from RAM to GPU is probably the bottleneck.

Comment: It seems you both are right! If I decrease timesteps number, the speed difference between GPU and CPU improoved (in GPU favor).